# chemfig: abbreviate a constitutional formula with round brackets

Tags: chemfig

I'd like to abbreviate a constitutional formula with round brackets. 
In math mode it works:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{CH_3-(CH_2)_3-CH_3}$ instead of $\mathrm{CH_3-CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-CH_3}$
\end{document}
```

But how I do this within a chemfig formula?

I tried:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{CH_3-(CH_2)_3-CH_3} instead of \chemfig{CH_3-CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-CH_3}
\end{document}
```

But it does not work like expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(` and `)` are special chars reserved to indicate bifurcation.
You must enclose them between braces to make them invisible to the chemfig parser:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{CH_3-{(}CH_2{)}_3-CH_3} instead of \chemfig{CH_3-CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-CH_3}
\end{document}
```

[image]